# javascript array declaration with OR

Tags: javascript, arrays

i found a javascript line below while studing a project :

```
var array = array || [];    // <--- confusion here (what does || mean)
```

can anyone tell me why someone declared the array like above instead of :
 `var array = [];`

**UPDATE** : after having the answers i figured out more readable way to do the above :

```
if(array == undefined) 
    var array = [];
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there should be no difference here - `array` must be undefined, because when the expression is evaluated, `array` has just been declared.

Comment: @Eric No : array may already have been declared. This is frequent in multi-files constructs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference with simply `var array = [];` is that if there already is an existing value, this value isn't replaced with `[]`.

It works because

- `var` doesn't declare a new variable if it is already declared in the scope ([variable declarations are hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting))
- `||` [returns the first non falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_%28.7C.7C%29) (for example a defined array)

this is equivalent to

```
var array; // does nothing if array is already declared in the same scope
if (!array) array = [];
```

This kind of construct is frequent when you have a modular code and don't want to impose an order of import : you may have many files starting with the same line :

```
var myModule = myModule || {};
```

Here's an example : [SpaceBullet source code](https://github.com/Canop/SpaceBullet/tree/master/src) (look at the first lines of the js files).

Comment: Seems more like a error, should have been `array = array || [];` without the var prefix. Since its basically redclaring the same variable name.

Comment: it depends. There's no problem with an additional `var`.

Comment: so u mean i can also do something like `if(array == undefined) var array = [];` ?

Comment: To be less risky, I would always use `window.` instead of `var` (assuming this is global scope) to ensure it validates, lints, compiles, etc.

Comment: @AshokDamani in fact you're mostly right. It's better to test with `undefined` but the code is, strictly speaking, more equivalent to the code I show (that is it would also replace array if its value was "" for example).

Comment: @Dave This would be very different. You usually don't want to add variables to the global scope.

Comment: `array = array || [];` (without `var`) would result in a global if it doesn't already exist, no?

Comment: In my experience, if you're using this pattern, it's because you're playing with the global scope. Anywhere else and you have enough control to define it properly in the first place.

Comment: It's a common pattern for optional function arguments @Dave

Comment: @finishingmove for optional function arguments, you don't need the `var`.

Comment: @finishingmove ah but in that case you don't use `var` at all and it's all fine

Comment: Unless you're using a different local variable name, but yes.

Comment: @Dave Even for global scope variables I prefer to use `var`. A minor reason being that the same code could be used for nodejs and a better reason being that the intent (not changing a standard variable) is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

This means: *If there is a value or array is initialized, assign it to the variable, otherwise, initialize this variable as an empty array.*

You will see similar declarations with {}

```
var someObject = anObject || {};
```